# Make a string variable from a random array

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DotComTestDrive {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String stringOfWords[] = {"Do", "You", "Like", "Me"};
        boolean correctOrder = true;
        int numberOfResets = 0;
        String correctString;
        String realString[];

        while (correctOrder == true) {

            System.out.println();

            for (int x = 0 ; x < 4 ; x++) {

                int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 4);

                System.out.print(stringOfWords[rand]);
                System.out.print(" ");

                numberOfResets++;
            }
            // Place If statement here to change correctOrder to false when the new string is "Do You Like Me "

        }

        System.out.println(numberOfResets);
    }
}
```

My main goal for this is to try and get the new random four words that
it prints out into an `String[]` so I can then use an If statement to
see if the string matches the original. Then I will make the `boolean`
"correctOrder" be `false`, ending the loop.

I know it is simple and sorry if its not a great or clear question.
Just trying to learn the basics and anything helps, thanks!

Comment: Do you want just to shuffle the words from an array?

Comment: Btw why anyone would use `boolean == true` in a boolean statement? Why not just `while(correctOrder)`?

Comment: first off, I'd suggest you to either change the name of `correctOrder` to `incorrectOrder` , or switch the boolean state around. That variable name is misleading, it makes no sense that correctOrder=false means the string is in the correct order.

Comment: Take a look at [Collections#Shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)). It's a static method, meaning you can call it from anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to use a list and shuffle it every time you loop.

```
Map<K,V> map = xxxx;
List<Map.Entry<K,V>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<K,V>>(map.entrySet());

// each time you want a different order.
Collections.shuffle(list);

for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry: list) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to put these `String`s in `realString`, you should do as follows/

- initialise this `Array`
- assign one of its elements in your `for` loop.

For example:

```
String realString[] = new String[4];

while(correctOrder == true){
    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){ 
        int rand = (int) (Math.random()*4);
        System.out.print(stringOfWords[rand]);
        System.out.print(" ");

        realString[x] = stringOfWords[rand];
    }
}
```

Also, since I'm at it, I'd suggest you to change a few things in your code:

- no need to specify `== true`: a `boolean` variable can be tested by itself.
- the use of the `Random` class (instead of `Math` one) is often preferred. You could have a `final Random r = new Random()` and get a random `int` in the range `[0, 4[` by simply using `r.nextInt(4)`